# project developed on window VS 2015, run/deployed on mac

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Can a mvc core project developed on window VS 2015, run/deployed on mac? I have developed a core project using VS2015, now i want to host it on both window and mac server. Is it possible to deploy it on both platform. Or i have to develop the separate application.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things need to be changed in the .csproj to run it on mac and recompiled / restored, but the same project can be deployed to either OS.  That is the whole point of .Net Core.

Mac Details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet using vscode since VS 2017 still in beta for Mac